# AngularJS: Receiving posted data while file uploading

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

My current scenario is: I've doing nesting repetition like follow:

```
$scope.uploadPic = function(file) 
{

    alert($scope.taskdetails.id);       //task_id e.g 21
    alert($rootScope.job_id);   //job_id e.g 12
    file.upload = Upload.upload(
    {
      url: 'http://localhost/mobile-data/upload_file.php',
      data: {
                file: file,
                task_id: $scope.taskdetails.id,
                job_id: $rootScope.job_id
            },

    });
    file.upload.then(function (response) {
      $timeout(function () {
        file.result = response.data;
      });
    }, function (response) {
      if (response.status > 0)
        $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
    }, function (evt) {
      // Math.min is to fix IE which reports 200% sometimes
      file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
    });
}
```

but on my `upload_file.php` i can't receive the values for:

```
task_id: $scope.taskdetails.id,
job_id: $rootScope.job_id
```

in `console.log` they are working fine. but on server side it is not receiving.
here is code of my `upload_file.php`

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$task_id = $_POST["task_id"];
$file = $_FILES["file"];
$job_id = $_POST["job_id"];
var_dump($task_id);
var_dump($job_id);
```

but on `var_dump` it only print `null`. Help me to receive the values correctly..

Comment: You should tag this question PHP too. I haven't developed in PHP for years, but I'd recommend var_dumping $POST, $GET and $FILES.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you verify what is actually being sent towards the server? (You can do this using the F12 development tools in most browsers.)

What is the type of `data.file`? When looking at your php code, I assume you're sending a json object to the server, so I would guess the browser fails to serialize `file` into a json object, and ends up sending an empty request to the server.
To fix this, you could read the file as base64 data so that you can send it along as a string in the json data object:

```
var data = {
    file: '',
    task_id: $scope.taskdetails.id,
    job_id: $rootScope.job_id
};

if($window.FileReader) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function() {
        data.file = reader.result;

        $http.post('http://localhost/mobile-data/upload_file.php', data);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

The file will then be sent as a string formatted as `data:image/png;base64,...` to the server (you can see this in the F12 tools).

Arrived in php, this base64 string needs to be decoded to get back the file:

```
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$task_id = $_POST['task_id'];
$job_id = $_POST['job_id'];

if(isset($_POST['file']) && ($_POST['file'] != NULL)
    && preg_match('/data:([^;]*);base64,(.*)/', $_POST['file'], $matches)) {

    if($matches && (count($matches) > 2)) {
        $datatype = $matches[1];            
        $file = base64_decode($matches[2]);
    }
}
```

Note, `$_FILES` won't work when you're sending your data as a json object to the server.

---

EDIT: just noticed you're using [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/wiki/PHP-Example)? Then the data does not get sent as a json object, but as the usual form urlencoded data. In that case you shouldn't have this line in your php code:

```
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

And to send the data in javascript:

```
Upload.upload({
    url: 'http://localhost/mobile-data/upload_file.php', 
    method: 'POST',
    file: file,
    sendFieldsAs: 'form',
    fields: {
        task_id: $scope.taskdetails.id,
        job_id: $rootScope.job_id
    }
 })
```

Comment: Thanks alot for answering. file is receiving correctly. But issue is being in data that is sending.. let the console log is just like this: `----------------------------259371869026485
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="task_id"

21
-----------------------------259371869026485-
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="job_id"

12`
but i can't get `job_id` and `task_id` on server side.

Comment: You earned my respect Sir... Yes you identified correctly. i shouldn't decode it.. Now its working very fine.